# init.d/networking restart

Tags: ubuntu, networking, restart

I am using ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.
I noticed something...when I am in my root directory and try /etc/init.d/networking restart, it works, yet when I go to the directory (i.e /etc/init.d) and type networking restart, I get an error message saying

> networking:command not found

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the [current directory](http://www.linfo.org/current_directory.html) (`.`) is not in your [`$PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (for [good reasons](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default)).

You need to specify the path explicitly:

```
cd /etc/init.d
./networking restart
```